# JavaMail Content-Disposition before first line of attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, attachment, content-disposition

I'm trying to attach multiple files to an email.

It is working fine, apart from the fact that the text file is missing the first line.

Note: All error handling removed for readability. Also, assume correct setup of To / From / Subject etc. (the email sends perfectly - apart from attachment issue).

First, here's the code I'm using:

```
MimeMessage oMessage = new MimeMessage(oSession);
// Create a multipart message
Multipart oMultiPart = new MimeMultipart();

// Create the message part 
BodyPart oMessageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

// Set the Message Body
String strFormat = oEmail.getFormat();
String strBody = oEmail.getBody();

oMessageBodyPart.setContent(strBody,strFormat);
oMultiPart.addBodyPart(oMessageBodyPart);


List<String> oAttachmentNames = oEmail.getAttachments();
for (String strAttachmentName : oAttachmentNames)
{                
 // Parse file from URL
 URL oURL = new URL(strAttachmentName);

 MimeBodyPart oAttachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart(oURL.openStream());

     oAttachmentPart.setFileName(strAttachmentName);
     oMultiPart.addBodyPart(oAttachmentPart);
}
// Add all contents (body + attachments)
oMessage.setContent(oMultiPart);
```

The text file is as follows by the way:

```
This is the Test file
   (intentional line break)
Line 1
Line 2
```

Here's the debug output:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
boundary="----=_Part_0_29194312.1354442889470"

------=_Part_0_29194312.1354442889470
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Plain Text Email.

------=_Part_0_29194312.1354442889470
This is the Test file
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
filename="http://mysite.com/temp/Test.txt"

Line 1
Line 2

------=_Part_0_29194312.1354442889470--
.
250 OK id=1Tf6T5-0004E9-Nn
QUIT
```

Answer (score 3):

From my experience with several projects involving email messages, with or without attachments, I know the following to work flawlessly. I have always used the Java Activation framework to provide an extra layer of abstraction between my code and the diverse sources of data for email composition. This framework has been integrated into the standard Java distribution a couple of years ago, so you already have it. Below you find a link to some bite-size introduction to its usage, so I won't explain the workings, but just show you an excerpt from one of my latest projects involving sending multipart emails. Here is the code that configures an empty MimeMessage, given the email specifications provided in a Notification object. The notification object has an array of Attachment objects. An Attachment objects provides a byte array and some  metadata to help create a file attachment in the email.

```
private void configureMessage(Message message, Notification notification) throws MessagingException {
    DataHandler messageDataHandler = new DataHandler(notification.getMessage(), "text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
    if (notification.getAttachments() != null && !notification.getAttachments().isEmpty()) {
        log.debug("configureMessage: Adding attachments.");
        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // een body part voor de tekstuele boodschap
        BodyPart mainBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        mainBodyPart.setDataHandler(messageDataHandler);
        multipart.addBodyPart(mainBodyPart);

        for (Attachment attachment : notification.getAttachments()) {
            log.debugv("configureMessage: Adding attachment {0}.", attachment);
            // een body part voor de attachment
            MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            ByteArrayDataSource attachmentDataSource =
                    new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment.getBytes(), attachment.getMimeType());
            attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(attachmentDataSource));
            attachmentPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
            attachmentPart.setFileName(attachment.getFileName());
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
        }
        message.setContent(multipart);
    } else {
        log.debug("configureMessage: No attachments.");
        message.setDataHandler(messageDataHandler);
    }
}
```

As you see, all data that is to go into the message is first wrapped in a DataHandler. The textual message goes into a data handler like this:

```
  DataHandler messageDataHandler = new DataHandler(notification.getMessage(), "text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
```

If the input for a body part is not just a string, but some other form, then you use a DataSource, specific for the type of input you have. If you have a URL, then use a URLDataSource; if you have a file then use a FileDataSource. 
In this example we only deal with attachments whose data is a byte array generated somewhere else. Therefore the data source is a ByteArrayDataSource.

Here's a simple [introduction](http://www.slideshare.net/ejlp12/introduction-to-javabeans-activation-framework-v11) into the Activation Framework.